# UISplitViewController IOS9 dealloc

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, dealloc

I have an application targeting IOS7. The dealloc method is called for the version going from IOS7 to IOS8.4

Now I am working to support also IOS9 but the dealloc method is never called.
Have you got the same behaviour?

Comment: Make sure you don't hold reference to this controller (for example as main view controller of your app).

Comment: I am experiencing the same behavior. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I believe that this is also happening in iOS 11, xCode 9.